# Bot Framework: Getting the current user and Authentication experience

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory, botframework, bots

I'm creating a Chat bot using the [Microsoft BOT Framework v4](https://dev.botframework.com/).

The plan is a user will access a chat BOT from an internal company website which will be hosting the iframe provided by the Web Chat Channel.

We want to make a number of calls to a custom API that will return data specific to the user using the BOT. For example, when they ask "When is my next day off?" we return the amount.

In order for this to work we need to know who the current user is. I'm unaware of any way to get this from the web page the iframe is sitting on via c#.

So I have been looking into authentication with chat bots and have walked through the authentication example found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp). I have been able to get it working but I'd like to have a better user experience then having pop up windows and copying the token back to the bot.

So the questions I have are:

1. Is there a better sign in experience that the pop up windows from the example?
2. Am I able to get the username of the current user via the Web Chat Channel?

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54765707/integrating-azure-bot-in-web-application)